# Why isnt the text of my label getting updated in a static method? C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am currently working with a static method on my page (It is static because it works with other pages). At the end of this method I foreach the results of a list and give the x:name of my label (that i have created in my XAML page) a new text.

To test to see if it worked I write out the labels text in the log and the correct text indeed gets written out, however the text does not get updated on the app.

The code looks something like this:

```
public static MyPage currentpage = new MyPage();
```

This is the current page that i am working on. In order to reach the labels x:name I created this code.

And then this is the static method on this page also.

```
public static async Task loadTheData(string token) //method is static because i send a token from another page
    {
        ...

        foreach (var profileinfo in App.registeredUsers) //this is my list
        {
            currentpage.myXAMLlabel.Text = profileinfo.name; //this is the label where i assign the new text
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(currentpage.myXAMLlabel.Text); //the correct text gets written out in the log but the text does not get updated "visually" on the app
    }
```

So as I mentioned above, I get the correct text in the log but the text of the label does not get updated "visually" on the app screen.

I call the static method firstly from the specific iOS/Android folders:

```
 App.SuccessfulLoginAction.Invoke();
```

And on my app-page I have the following method:

```
  public static Action SuccessfulLoginAction
    {
        get
        {
            return new Action(async () =>
            {
                await MyPage.loadTheData(token);
            });

        }
    }
```

I could move the SuccessfulLoginAction to `MyPage` instead of having it on the `App` page. But the method has to still be static i suppose (?) in order for the iOS code to reach the `Action`.

How can I adjust my code to solve this problem?

Comment: This is the same for any GUI - you shouldn't block it. And your foreach() is very blocking.

Comment: The method has to be static in order for me to reach this from other pages. In order for me to talk to my page from this static method i created this code snippet: `public static MyPage currentpage = new MyPage(); ` but it is not working correctly.

Comment: The `static` is just ugly and a bad idea but not the core problem here.

Comment: Yeah I don't like working with static methods either. But I assume I need it in order to reach this method from other pages right?

Comment: There are always other (and better) ways, but the real issue is that forms/pages shouldn't know each other at all. This is a sign of biz logic in the UI. Study on MVVM.

Comment: Also post how you call this method.

Comment: Sure one second

Comment: Updated the post now with that code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, you are adding the `public static MyPage currentpage = new MyPage();` in the `MyPage` class?

If that's the case, your instance of `MyPage` in the `currentPage` variable, won't be the same instance that you see on the screen. The Debug message will show the instance that is not on screen. You could implement what you want with the singleton pattern.

**Get rid of the statics by using the MessagingCenter**

Or better yet, to get rid of the statics, make use of the `MessagingCenter` pub/sub mechanism or any other MVVM equivalent. Example for the `MessagingCenter`:

You can use the App class as the sender from your platform specific projects. Like this:

```
MessagingCenter.Send<App>((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Cur‌​rent, "myEvent")
```

Subscribe in your App class:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App>(this, "myEvent", ...)
```

If you want to subscribe in your page:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App>((App)Application.Current, "myevent", ...)
```

See [the docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/) for more information.

**Updating UI elements on the right thread**

You should also make sure to update UI elements on the Main Thread (which you probably won't be on because you are using async/await). As @SushiHangover mentioned in his answer by using `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
     currentpage.myXAMLlabel.Text = profileinfo.name;
});
```

Comment: Yeah messagecenter seems to be a better way to approach this. However I am not sure on how I can subscribe to the iOS-page where the message gets sent. For example this is how I send it from an iOS-page. `MessagingCenter.Send<userLogin_iOS>(this, "login");` and when I then try to subscribe from it on the page where I intend to use the data: `MessagingCenter.Subscribe<??> (this, "login", (sender) =>
      {

      });` I am not sure how I can subscribe to that specific iOS-page where it gets sent

Comment: You can use the `App` class as the sender. Like this: `MessagingCenter.Send<App>((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "myEvent")` and subscribe in your App class: `MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App>(this, "myEvent", ...)`. If you want to subscribe in your page: `MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App>((App)Application.Current, "myevent", ...)`. See [the docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/) for more info.

Comment: I have updated the answer to show the `MessagingCenter` part more clearly. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are updating any UI elements on the UI/main thread, i.e.:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    currentpage.myXAMLlabel.Text = profileinfo.name; //this is the label where i assign the new text
});
```

Comment: If it was a wrong thread, it would raise an exception rather than "not visually updating", wouldn't it?

Comment: @GSerg In iOS, UIKit would raise an inconsistant violation, but Android would not

Comment: The blocking is a sign that it isn't running on another thread. It should be, with proper syncing for the progress indication.

Comment: Look at the original code and my 1st comment here. But I am making the assumption that the Task is awaited, not started.

Comment: I get no exception when I add this code snippet but it does not solve the problem it seems like and when I write out the labels current text in the log it is null. Without this code I get the correct value in the log.

Comment: @Martman Can you add the call context of the `loadTheData` method to your question. Also how many objects are in `registeredUsers`  and why not just take the `Last` (via Linq)

Comment: I updated the post now on how I call the `loadTheData` method. It all starts off from the iOS folder that calls a method in the App. page. The method on the App.page then talks with the `loadTheData` method

Comment: I could move the `SuccessfulLoginAction`  to `MyPage` instead of having it on the  `App` page . But the method has to still be static i suppose in order for the iOS code to reach the `Action`

Comment: Ended up going for a messagingcenter solution instead of the static methods. Appreciate every help